# Why python scheduler runs just once?

Tags: python, django

I use the python scheduler to run a proces in an interval of 3 seconds.
But the ouput ( just a hello world ) run just one times. I run this function after the start of my django webserver, so it is necessary that this script run in the background.

**Question 1**: Why my script run just one, an not each second (value of delay is 3)

**Question 2**: Is this a good practice to run a script in the background or in an interval? I expact, that the script needs not more than 3 second to execute.

```
import sched, time
def startProcess(self):
    print("START PROCESS")
    print(time.time())
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    s.enter(3,1, self.initProcessHelloWorld)
    s.run()
    print(time.time())
    print("END PROCESS")
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question 1: The task only runs once because you (I suppose) only call the `startProcess` once. The `sched` set once task, the `initProcessHelloWorld`but only once. You need to do it `N`times if you want `N` calls to `initProcessHelloWorld`.

Answer to the question 2: It's a good idea but it's better to make a `daemon`. Here you are a [daemon package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) and an [example of a daemon](http://web.archive.org/web/20131017130434/http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/)

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, an other question about the Deamon-Package, i can not find a specification about the OS, so.. does it run on Windows too? Because, I just know Deamons form the Unix world.

Comment: @michael-mammut Sorry but I don´t... I only tried it on Unix Systems.
PS: If my answer help you, mark it as "answer"!